# How long does items in the engine last in general for standard size cars?

Tags: engine, vw, overheating, passat

I have a volkswagon passat wagon. It just reach 70000M and it is 2007 model. I recently check the engine at the dealership. Now they asked me to replace all the following items to fix engine overheat and engine noise that just happen a few days ago.

```
CYLINDER HEAD, REPLACE INTAKE VALVE
CAM CHAIN AND HYDRAULIC TENSIONER
SEAL SEAL RING X 2
A SENDER
D BOOT
COOL.ADD
FR ELECTR FAN
E ELECTR FAN
```

All these together will end up 6000K+. It will shoot up to 7000+ if I also change the timing belt.

The car is 2007 Passat wagon. 2.0T 4WD. A month ago there is overheat, the coolant meter shoot up to the red region twice. So I checked with them and they say replace fans and thermal sensor in engine will do the job. That Is about 1500. Then two weeks later, I found engine has a sound that feels like diesel car, but my car is gas. Also there are times I turn off the car but the engine fan is still on for a few minutes which I have never seen bwfore. So they check and say I need to replace bunch of stuff in the engine. I always maintain this car at the dealership and I dont drive as much everyday (about 15Miles normally). So it is unlikely that it will be damaged by my driving habit.

The question is:
How long does these components last normally? If I am spending this much money to repair the car. Maybe I should just buy a new one (a cheaper model).

Comment: To be quite honest, most of those things *should last for the life of the car*. When you say you had an overheat problem, what exactly was the problem? If you are wondering if they are trying to fleece you, this would let us know how to tell you what is what. Also, what year/model is your VW?

Comment: It is 2007 Passat wagon. 2.0T 4WD.  I di

Comment: It is 2007 Passat wagon. 2.0T 4WD. A month ago there is overheat, the coolant meter shoot up to the red region twice. So I checked with them and they say replace fans and thermal sensor in engine will do the job. That Is about 1500. Then two weeks later, I found engine has a sound that feels like diesel car, but my car is gas. Also there are times I turn off the car but the engine fan is still on for a few minutes which I have never seen bwfore. So they check and say I need to replace bunch of stuff in the engine.

Comment: Unfortunately, what they are telling you is probably right on the money (no pun intended). If drastic enough, overheating can cause all of the issues they are dealing with and more.

Comment: What else should I check? Because these people dont even check if I dont raise the concern about the noise. Also, I suppose the overheat problem should complete go away after they replace the fan and temperature sensor.

Comment: It's hard to know what exactly needs replacing without knowing what the exact noise is, or other conditions, and we can't do that. The dealer can, and has the scan tools which give a lot more information than you're going to get from checking for codes at AutoZone. What the dealer says needs replaced is probably correct, and yes, it's going to be expensive, as it will require quite a bit of labor hours by the book.

Comment: @dobey, there are two directions: 1. problem is not that serious and they ask for too much. 2. problem is more serious than what they describe and they did not find out. But I am more worry about the second problem now. Here is why, since the first overheat and they replace the fan and temperator sensor which cost 1500. They should have suggest a check on inside of the engine then I will be more convinced about their experience and skills. What they are saying is that because I didnt ask for it. Now I ask, then they do this, next time sth else on engine goes wrong, they will say the same thing

Comment: @dobey, Plus, the problem is not discovered from the code scan. They open the engine and then find out the problem.

Comment: Price a used engine, it may be a better buy than repairing yours at this cost

Comment: Why would they need to replace a cam belt AND a cam chain?

Comment: Mind you, for that money, Id rather just buy a new or low-mileage import engine and have it installed. It may even cost less.

Answer (score 1):

Engine internals can last a very long time. They are generally built to at least survive beyond the standard warranty term for the vehicle in question. This is typically 100K miles in modern vehicles.

However, improper maintenance, driving beyond the normal parameters of the engine, and contamination can cause rapid deterioration of service life. Given the items suggested by the dealer, it sounds like the head itself may have been damaged, and possibly a valve may have had contact with a piston. Overheating could have caused oiling issues, and the timing chain to stretch, which could cause the VVT system to not work properly, which could result in piston-valve contact. I'd say if you only have to replace the head, timing chain, seals, and fluids though, you've come out on the lucky side. The mechanic may find more things wrong though, once the oil pan and head come off, at which point the whole engine may need to be rebuilt or replaced.

Comment: So you suggest I ask them to check the oil pan and head as well?

Comment: I don't know what they have and have not actually done yet, so I am not suggesting anything. If you have a bent valve (which it sounds like is the case), then the head will need to removed for repair anyway, and once that happens, they may find more problems. And yes, the oil should be analyzed and the oil pan may need to come off as well. as a spun bearing is also a possibility. I'm just saying, prepare for the worst (engine replacement), so you'll know what to expect if it's the case.